# CodeLens showing wrong description for changeset

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, changeset, codelens

I updated the comment/description for a changeset and CodeLense is showing the old/not updated description

The changeset using CodeLense:

[image]

The changset using Team Explorer (showing the updated desc.)

[image]

Is there perhaps a difference between "Comment" and "Description"? (if yes, how can I update the Description)

Or do I have to clear some caches?

Comment: CodeLens runs a background job , so it may take some time for the change to be picked up.

Comment: I updated the comment 3 days ago. According to this article https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2014/05/23/codelens-team-indicators-processing-pipeline/ it should max. take one day

Comment: Are you using on-premise TFS or VSTS?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using VSTS, this could be caused by this issue: [Issues with CodeLens Feature in Visual Studio Team Services – 11/22 – Investigating](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsoservice/?p=12815).